# How to skip code in workbook2 when closing file?

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is when closing workbook2 I need to use code to automatically select No on a message box that pops up. This is how my code is laid out:

1. Workbook1 creates multiple files based on user input.
2. The loop in Workbook1 opens up Workbook2 and inputs data from Workbook1.
3. When the loop is done inputing data it closes workbook2 and a message box pops up with a Yes or No button on it.
4. User at this time should always select No.
5. Another window ask if the user would like to save and it should always be yes.
6. Loop continues until it has created all the files user has requested

I tried googling variations of my question but have not had much luck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 Dim JobName As String
 Dim lngLoop As Long
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Customer As String
 Dim LastRow  As Long
 Dim iCus As Integer
 Dim CompanyName As String
 Dim d As Long
 Dim strDir As Variant
 Dim DIV As String
 Dim XL As Excel.Application
 Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook
 Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
 Dim ActBook As Workbook
 Dim CurrentFile As Workbook
 Dim NewFileType As String
 Dim NewFile As String
 Dim QTR_NUM As String
 Dim MFG As String
 Dim Job As String
 Dim visitdate As Variant
 Dim visitdate_text As String
 Dim Quote_Request As Worksheet
 Dim QTR As Workbook
 Dim QTRLOG As Workbook
 Dim FORM As Workbook
 Dim DCSProgram As Workbook
 Dim ILast As Long
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim k As Integer
 Dim CustomerIDNum As String
 Dim QTRNUM As String
 Dim FolderName As String

'Creates Quote For Each MFG
 For j = 0 To QTRList.ListCount - 1
 Set QTRLOG = Workbooks.Open("C:\QTR LOG.xlsm")
 Set QTR = Workbooks.Open("C:\QTR.xlsx")

'CODE TO INPUT DATA FROM USERFORM NEW QTR

 With DCSProgram.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
    ILast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To ILast
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = MFG Then
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B7").Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B8").Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B9").Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B12").Value = .Cells(i, 5).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B13").Value = .Cells(i, 6).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B14").Value = .Cells(i, 7).Value
                QTR.Sheets(1).Range("B15").Value = .Cells(i, 8).Value

    End If: Next: End With

    With QTRLOG.Sheets("QTR_LOG")
        ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To ILast
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
                    .Cells(i, 2) = QTRList.List(j)
                    '.Cells(i, 3) = FORM.Sheets(1).Range("H11").Value
                    .Cells(i, 5) = JobName
                    .Cells(i, 8) = "OPEN"
                    .Cells(i, 9) = QTR.Sheets(1).Range("H9").Value
    End If: Next: End With

QTRLOG.Save
QTRLOG.Close

QTR.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\2. QUOTE REQUESTS\" & JobName & "\" _
& " DCS QTR " & QTRList.List(j) & " " & JobName & " (" & CustomerIDNum & ") " & visitdate_text & " .xlsx", _
FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True

'Code To Close File After Creating It
QTR.Close


Next j
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\2. QUOTE REQUESTS", vbNormalFocus)


Unload NewQTR

End Sub
```

When this code runs a msgbox appears from the workbook QTR. I dont want the user to have to click yes or no at this time. I want to automatically select No and continue on to the next file. This process is repeated for each MFG.

Code in QTR:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MSG1 = MsgBox("Are you ready to email to MFG?", vbYesNo, "EMAIL MFG")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then

'Code to create email and attached workbook as PDF

Else
Const kPath As String = "C:\"
Const kFile As String = "Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\9. PROGRAM FILES\1. QUOTE REQUEST\QUOTE REQUEST LOG.xlsm"

Dim TOTALFOB As Double
Dim TOTALWC As Double
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim INWBK As Workbook
Dim QTR_NUM As String
Dim ILast As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim TOTMFG As Variant
Dim TOTWC As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim TOTALTIME As Variant

Set INWBK = ThisWorkbook

With Sheets("QTR")
    LR = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    TOTALFOB = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("I23:I" & LR))
End With


TOTALWC = TOTALFOB + INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("D18").Value


QTR_NUM = INWBK.Sheets("QTR").Range("H7").Value

TOTALTIME = INWBK.Sheets("WS_LOG").Range("J3").Value

Rem Set Wbk in case it's open
On Error Resume Next
Set Wbk = Workbooks(kFile)
On Error GoTo 0
Rem Validate Wbk
If Wbk Is Nothing Then Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(kPath & kFile)




With Workbooks("QUOTE REQUEST LOG.xlsm").Sheets("QTR_LOG")
    ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To ILast
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
            .Cells(i, 6) = TOTALFOB
            .Cells(i, 7) = TOTALWC
            .Cells(i, 10) = TOTALTIME


End If: Next: End With



Wbk.Save
Wbk.Close

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In order to "skip" the code you can just comment off the lines of code you want to skip. Is it what you are asking for? Best regards,

Comment: Do you mind posting the whole code?

Comment: Have you tried some GoTo statements?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is avoiding some `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event handler placed in "ThisWorkbook" code to be executed, then you must "enclose" the code lines that close the workbook like follows

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
' your code that closes the workbook
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Ok, tried this... Does not work. A message box pops up with yes or no button and i have to click no.I want the code in my loop to automatically select no. Ive seen other posts with your solution when i google my question but it does not work in this case.

Comment: as for not having msgbox asking "Are you ready to email to MFG?", assuming you don't want to comment that line, you could add a "Workbook_Open" event handler in "ThisWorkbook" module where to transfer the emailing code that runs if the search for an open workbook named "QTR LOG.xlsm" returns false

Comment: where does the "Code in QTR" actually resides? in a standard module or in "ThisWorkbook" module? in a normal sub or in a event handler?

Comment: as for the saving question, step through your code to get the statement that throws it. I guess it must be the "QTR.SaveAs...  .xlsx" statement which asks to save a ".xslm" file (as "QTR" must be having code in it) to a ".xlsx" one. that will have Excel pop out a message to ask you whether to confirm that or not.    If so place a "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" statement right before the "QTR.Saves..." statement and a "Application.DisplayAlerts = True" right after it

Answer (score 0):

**Exit Sub** *before* **end if** is making the code exit earlier.

So remove the above mentioned one and check.